# How to resolve the hydration error when using an rxjs interval in a server-side rendered Angular app?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-universal

I have an Angular 17 server-side rendered app which uses an rxjs interval to periodically make a call to an API GET endpoint. The code is something like this:

```js
interval(5000).pipe(
        startWith('Loading...'),
        switchMap(() => this.apiService.get())
```

However, when I run this I get this error from Angular in de browser console:

> NG0506: Angular hydration expected the ApplicationRef.isStable() to emit `true`, but it didn't happen within 10000ms. Angular hydration logic depends on the application becoming stable as a signal to complete hydration process. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0506

I've tried multiple solutions already, like:

- Wrapping the interval with `isPlatformBrowser()`
- `afterNextRender()` in the constructor of my component
- `inject(NgZone).runOutsideAngular()` in the constructor

However, none of them give the result I want (a call every 5 seconds) and every time I get the hydration error. So, what is the best approach, when do I need to use which method?

Comment: Do you mind adding the example code of your Angular project?? I'm not sure how  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) handles [SSR](https://angular.io/guide/ssr), so if that's an issue, a github project for us to fork would be amazing and helpful for we all that want to help you :)

Comment: I had a similar issue yesterday. Mine was "NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <body> but found <div>", it turned out that I left an empty row at the beginning of the 'app.component.html' document and for some reason angular didn't like it. When I removed it, everything returned to normal with hydration. Could it be something like that, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the start of the interval or ngAfterViewInit did not work for me. What did work was using ngZone like this:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  this.sub = interval(10 * 1000)
    .pipe(
      startWith(0),
      mergeMap(() => this.http.get<TimeTable>(`/api/time-tables/${id}`)),
    )
    .subscribe((timeTable) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.timeTable = timeTable;
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so far as i can see ,that the Angular hydration process is not completing within the expected timeframe. Angular hydration is the process of converting the server-rendered HTML into a fully functional Angular application on the client-side. The error occurs when the ApplicationRef.isStable() method does not emit true within 10 seconds, indicating that the application is not becoming stable.

also look in it from the following view

If there are long-running tasks or asynchronous operations that prevent the application from becoming stable, it can lead to this error. In this case, the interval operator might be causing the issue.
or if the API call made by this.apiService.get() takes a long time to complete, it can delay the application from becoming stable.

or it could be that there is an infinite loop or recursive function call in the code, it can prevent the application from becoming stable.

i don't have really a solution but the prevension that is to increse the time interval to somthing like 20sec

```
interval(20000).pipe(
        startWith('Loading...'),
        switchMap(() => this.apiService.get()
```

it is also worth to look in to the performance because it is also possible that the cause could be something else.

Comment: Isnt it better to use `timer` which has a delay parameter ( `10000` ), and you can set a timer of `5000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Observable.interval()` method to create an observable that emits an event every 5 seconds, and then use the `mergeMap()` operator to call your API service. like this

```js
Observable
  .interval(5000)
  .mergeMap(() => this.apiService.get())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

This ensures that your service calls are made synchronously that is the service at the 2nd interval will only be called after the 0th interval’s call has been completed and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official solution of this problem](https://angular.io/errors/NG0506). Seems your method is called on app initialization phase and that would be why you get this error.
Try this:

```
inject(NgZone).runOutsideAngular(() => {
    interval(5000).pipe(
      startWith('Loading...'),
      switchMap(() => this.apiService.get())
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
})
```

This should solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error NG0506 is related to Angular's expectation that the application should become stable during the hydration process, but it doesn't happen.

You can try using both `isPlatformBrowser()` and `NgZone` Together

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        interval(5000)
          .pipe(
            startWith('Loading...'),
            switchMap(() => this.apiService.get())
          )
          .subscribe((result) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
              // here you can handle the result inside Angular zone if needed
            });
          });
      });
```

You can also try delaying the first api call untill after rendering as the first doesn't happend untill the component is fully initialized. You can use `AfterViewInit` to delay this call.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    interval(5000)
      .pipe(
        startWith('Loading...'),
        switchMap(() => this.apiService.get())
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        // here you can handle the result within Angular zone if needed
      });
  }
```

Also you need to make sure that intervals are cleaned up after the component is destryed to avoid memory leaks.

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.alive.next(false);
    this.alive.complete();
  }
```

Let me know if this works.